# Terraform - what's the correct way to create a EKS cluster and apply manifests to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I have the following situation: I want to have a Terraform configuration in which I:

1. Create a EKS cluster
2. Install some manifests to it using `kubectl_manifest` resource.

So I essence, I have the following configuration:

```
... all the IAM stuff needed for the cluster

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.50"
    }

    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = ">= 1.7.0"
    }


  }
}

provider "aws" { }

provider "kubectl" {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
    config_context = aws_eks_cluster.this.arn # tried this also, with no luck
}


resource "aws_eks_cluster" "my-cluster" {
... the cluster configuration
}
... node group yada yada..

resource "null_resource" "update_kubeconfig" {
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster --region us-east-1"
   }
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "some_manifest" {
   yaml_body = <some_valid_yaml>

   depends_on = [null_resource.update_kubeconfig]
}
```

So my hope is that after the `null_resource.update_kubeconfig` runs, and updates the `.kube/config` (which it does; checked), the `kubectl_manifest.some_manifest` will pick up on it and use the newly updated configuration. But it doesn't.

I don't have currently the error message in hand, but essentially what happens is: It tries to communicate the previously created cluster (I have previously - now not existing - clusters in the kubeconfig). Then it throws an error of "can't resolve DNS name" of the old cluster.

So it seems that the kubeconfig file is loaded somewhere in the beginning of the run, and it isn't being refreshed when the `kubectl_manifest` resource is being created.

What is the right way to handle this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Terraform code itself creating the Cluster, you can refer that in provider configuration,

```
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "main" {
  name = aws_eks_cluster.my-cluster.name
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = aws_eks_cluster.my-cluster.endpoint

  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.main.token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(aws_eks_cluster.my-cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
}
```

Comment: It only works when your eks cluster is already creadted, if it doesn't exist yet, data will be null and the provider won´t be properly configured. Best way is https://stackoverflow.com/a/76309707/7207673

Answer (score 1):

The `aws eks update-kubeconfig` command will add the cluster context to your kubeconfig file but it doesn't switch to that context for `kubectl` commands. You can solve this a few different ways.

1. Update your local-exec command to include `; kubectl config use-context my-cluster`. This will update the global context after the file has been updated.
2. Add a `--kubeconfig ~/.kube/my-cluster` option to the local-exec command. Any `kubectl` commands should then use this option which keeps your cluster config is a separate file.
3. Update your `kubectl` commands to use `--context my-cluster` which will set the cluster context only for that command.
4. Update your kubectl provider to use the config_context with the value aws_eks_cluster.this.name. Contexts in the kubeconfig file are based on cluster names and not AWS ARNs.

Any of those options should work and it depends on how you like to manage your config.

Personally, I prefer to keep my clusters in separate config files because they're easier to share and I export `KUBECONFIG` in different shells instead of changing contexts back and forth.